# Can I select the first record from a collection property across a collection of objects?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an `IEnumerable<Document>`. Each `Document` has a property `IEnumerable<Event>`. I want to extract the first event (as ordered by `Event.Id`) from each document, and return this as an `IEnumerable<Event>`.

Is it possible to achieve this in a single database call?

Comment: do you use LINQ to query your database?

Answer (score 0):

Something like that ?

```
var firstEvents = docs.Select(x => x.Events.OrderBy(y => y.Id).First());
```